# Routing to subnet of a shared internet connection

Tags: networking, routing

Greeting, I have a mobile wifi router (192.168.8.1) and an Ubuntu PC Wifi(dhcp).
I have purchased a LAN/WIFI router for playing with IoT devices. I set Ubuntu to share the internet connection and have connected PC ethernet port to WLAN of the new router(DHCP, devices see 192.168.3.1). Everything works fine except that connecting from PC to 192.168.3.x device I have to disconnect from the internet wifi and connect to the new router wifi.

My question is how to set a routing on the PC to see 192.168.3.x addresses staying on the original wifi network?

Answer (score 0):

You probably wanted to write that the Ethernet port on the PC is connected to the **WAN** port of the new router. WLAN=wireless LAN, i.e. Wi-Fi. The cable cannot be connected to Wi-Fi (WLAN).

#### Situation

There is an issue in this connection of the cable to the WAN port of the new router. The WAN port is designed to connect to the Internet and has dynamic NAT turned on by default. Through it, you will not connect from the PC to the LAN network of the new router.

#### Solution #1

a) Find out what address the connection network between the PC and the new router has. It must be different from 192.168.8.0/24 and also from 192.168.3.0/4. Put these commands on PC to get details:

```
ip addr
ip neigh
```

I will suppose that it is e.g. 192.168.100.0/24 network and WAN port of the new router is visible as a neighbor address 192.168.100.2.

b) Turn off the NAT on the new router.

c) Add a new static route on the PC for the network 192.168.3.0/24 so that the next hop address is the same as the IP address of the WAN port of the new router.

```
sudo ip route add 192.168.3.0/24 via 192.168.100.2
```

#### Solution #2

Connect the cable from the PC to the LAN port of the new router. Leave the WAN port unplugged. Turn off the DHCP server in the new router. The router will only behave like a bridge and at the same time Wi-Fi access point. Addresses will be assigned by the PC through connection sharing service.